# Losing first few pings on an asymetric network

Tags: networking, centos, routing

I have a set of CentOS 7 machines that all have two NICs, one connected to a subnet with a default gateway, one that is entirely self-contained.
[image: Network diagram]

When I send pings from an internal node to another node in subnet 1 (with the default gateway), I have no problems. When I send pings from an internal node to another node in subnet 2, the first few pings get lost before it figures out how to send/respond to them. I think that this is a noob routing or metrics issue, but could someone give me more detail on where to look, or what to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was no connectivity at all through router 2. The system was failing for the first few pings, then routing the pings over router 1 in order to get them to pass through.

Answer (score 1):

It could be normal behavior, if there is no communication between the nodes, and then you start pings, the host first needs to resolve the IP address to MAC address, and during the time it waits to hear back on arp request, the pings will timeout. You can verify this by running another ping immediately after the first one, and see if it still times out.